# gwt border between columns

Tags: css, gwt, border

i'm developping a smal web application with gwt and one of my vues containes a table that i programmed with cellTable, but the problem is that the css by default of gwt dosen't make borders between columns

Nb : I find how to make borders but only at the extremities and not inter-columns thanks to the property : "borde-style"

so please could you tell me how can i make borders between the columns of my cellTable ?

Answer (score 0):

By default GWT uses css themes. So you have to find out the css class for table adn specially for cells and there you can change the css.

Comment: It's the theme css you are using. By default GWt uses Standard theme in module.gwt.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

`cellTableObject.setBordered(true);` sets the border columnwise also